# What are the Maven 2 Coordinates for OpenDS SDK?

Tags: maven-2, sdk, dependencies, ldap, opends

I have been playing around with the OpenDS SDK (not the full OpenDS Server/Platform) to implement a simple LDAP listener to front a service my application provides.

I have not been able to find the Maven 2 coordinates for such SDK. This is the SDK site https://www.opends.org/wiki/page/LDAPSDK

I would like to know if the dependency is available in any public Maven repository.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

After contacting a person related to OpenDS, I learned that it is not likely that the OpenDS artifacts will be available at any Maven repository.

However, this same person pointed at OpenDJ (http://opendj.forgerock.org/) and the OpenDJ SDK available in this repository http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/). UnboundID's LDAP SDK has some features not available in other SDKs, for example, an in-memory directory server and asynchronous operations. The standard edition is cost-free, but commercial support is available if required.

Comment: Besides being cost-free, is it open source?

Comment: The UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java is free to use and redistribute in open source or proprietary applications under the GPLv2, LGPLv2.1 and the UnboundID Free Use License. It doesn't have any third-party dependencies

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand if I have access to the source code. Does UnboundID LDAP SDK give access to its source code? Thanks for your reply